# Java openCV video processing frames/s

Tags: java, opencv, video, image-processing

I have a task to write program with 1 camera, 1 kinect, a lot of video processing and then controlling a robot.

This code just shows captured video frames without processing, but I only have 20 frames/s approximately. The same simple frames displaying program in Matlab gave me 29 frames/s. I was hoping that I will win some speed in Java, but it doesn't look like that, am I doing sth wrong? If not, how I can increase the speed?

```
    public class Video implements Runnable {
    //final int INTERVAL=1000;///you may use interval
    IplImage image;
    CanvasFrame canvas = new CanvasFrame("Web Cam");
    public Video() {
        canvas.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        FrameGrabber grabber = new VideoInputFrameGrabber(0); // 1 for next camera
        int i=0;
        try {
            grabber.start();
            IplImage img;
            int g = 0;

            long start2 = 0;
            long stop = System.nanoTime();
            long diff = 0;
            start2 = System.nanoTime();
            while (true) {

                img = grabber.grab();
                if (img != null) {
                   // cvFlip(img, img, 1);// l-r = 90_degrees_steps_anti_clockwise
                   // cvSaveImage((i++)+"-aa.jpg", img);
                    // show image on window
                    canvas.showImage(img);

                }
                g++;
                if(g%200 == 0){
                    stop = System.nanoTime();
                    diff = stop - start2;
                    double d = (float)diff;
                    double dd = d/1000000000;
                    double dv = dd/g;
                    System.out.printf("frames = %.2f\n",1/dv);
                }
                 //Thread.sleep(INTERVAL);
            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }



  public static void main(String[] args) {
        Video gs = new Video();
        Thread th = new Thread(gs);
        th.start();
    }
}
```